# Javascript Post inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, post, click

This is what I usually see:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

But I want to do this and it isn't really working:

```
<input type="submit" class='button_red' value="Create Pool" id="button" onclick="CreatePool()"><br />

function CreatePool(){
        $.post("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
}
```

Why not and shouldn't it? I'm getting the impression post will only work inside an event listener... but the above are just two ways of saying the same thing correct?

Comment: what is the error in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: CreatePool is not defined`
Try to declare the function before using-it.

```
<script>
    function CreatePool(){
        $.post("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
}
</script>

<input type="submit" class='button_red' value="Create Pool" id="button" onclick="CreatePool()"><br />
```

[Check this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/wsj8xnnz/)

Comment: Or possible use predefiined variable that already declared, `$` for example: http://jsfiddle.net/3u0vyz2h/

Comment: @stdob-- yah, i forgot this. +1 for hint

Comment: Jeez... this could really be the problem... too bad I deleted all the function code is a spat of anger, lol. It is good though, it seems like sometimes it has to be at the end and sometimes it has to be at the beginning, unintuitive.... But I suspect now, that this is a false impression.... functions need to be declared before they are used, right? I probably got the false impression because, at one point, I had java includes in the middle of the page making me think function X had to be at the end. I'll definitely try this when I get home.

Comment: To avoid situation like this use  something like this $("selector").on("click", function); or $("selector").on("click", function(){ ....});